# Insert image with specific size in a table cell in Word document

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, office-interop

What I try is to create a pdf file from an order passed in my Asp.NET MVC application.

I must add the product picture in th first cell of the Order Items table in the OrderTemplateFR.docx.

The code below works but keeps the real image size and because of large image size the form of the document is not correct.

The question is if there is a way to insert an image with specific size.

I can save image in another place in order to resize and add the modified image into the document etc... but I'm not sure if it will be the best solution.

What do you think ?

```
    public static void SaveOrderAsPdf()
    {
        using (CapronWebSiteEntities dc = new Models.CapronWebSiteEntities())
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = null;
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            try
            {
                //Get cart content and totals
                var cartItems = CartHelper.GetCart();

                string pth = GeneralHelper.WordTemplatesPath + @"OrderTemplateFR.docx";
                var order = SessionHelper.NewOrder;
                var client = SessionHelper.CurrentClient;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(pth))
                {
                    string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".docx";
                    System.IO.File.Copy(pth, tempPath);

                    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                    doc = app.Documents.Open(tempPath);
                    app.Visible = false;

                    doc.Bookmarks["AccountNumber"].Select();
                    app.Selection.TypeText(client.CompteClient);

                    //...

                    var items = (from ro in dc.abwebcomcs where ro.NoCommande == order.NoCommande orderby ro.NoLigneCommande select ro).ToList();
                    int i = 1;
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        i++;
                        doc.Tables[2].Rows.Add();

                        var product = cartItems.Where(ro => ro.RefNo == item.CodeArticleprestto).First();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = doc.Tables[2].Cell(i, 1).Range;

                        rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(string.Format(@"{0}{1}.jpg", GeneralHelper.LocalPhotosPath, product.PhotoPath), ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                        doc.Tables[2].Cell(i, 2).Select();
                        app.Selection.TypeText(product.Name);

                        //...
                    }

                    string pdfPath = OrdersPath + "Order_" + order.NoCommande + ".pdf";
                    doc.SaveAs(pdfPath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);

                    dc.SaveChanges();

                    doc.Close();
                    app.Quit();
                }
                else
                    GeneralHelper.ParseError(new Exception("Template doesn't exist"), "Prepare order");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GeneralHelper.ParseError(ex, "ValidateInstallationTrackingForm");
                if (doc != null)
                    doc.Close();
                if (app != null)
                    app.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For info, 
I found the solution:

```
       var shape = rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(string.Format(@"{0}{1}.jpg", GeneralHelper.LocalPhotosPath, product.PhotoPath), ref missing, ref missing, ref missing).ConvertToShape();
                        shape.HeightRelative = 8f;
                        shape.WidthRelative = 10f;
```

Comment: Tip: If the table column is set to a specific width (rather than allowed to resize with content) it will automatically resize the InlineShape you add to fit within the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found the code above, it works. Thanks again.